# How can I find out what application and application error keeps disabling my IIS 10 Application Pool?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-10

I have two Application Pools, Prod_Apps_Pool and Prod_Mobs_Pool. For some reason, the Prod_Apps_Pool will keep stopping, but the Prod_Mobs_Pool will keep running just fine. I *do* understand that it's the Rapid-Fail Protection that is turning off the pool; what I don't understand is what failing specific process is causing this.

Looking at Event Viewer, I do get a System Error that says "Application pool 'Prod_Apps_Pool' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool." Prior to this error, I have several warnings about processes serving the pool exceeding time limits during shut down, as well as processes requesting a recycle due to reaching a virtual memory limit.

I do not see anything in the Application Log, nor anything in the W3SVC# logs IIS logs. If I had to guess, I would say that these processes that are exceeding time limits are counting as "failures", the maximum number of failed processes in a given time limit is being hit, and then the Rapid-Fail Response is being triggered stopping the application pool. I would further guess that one of the applications in the pool specifically is causing these issues.

How can I specifically find out which application is causing this to happen? The only thing I have seen suggested so far is to put every single application in the pool into it's own pool, then find out which pool is shutting it down. But aside from the impracticality of separating a pool with dozens of applications into dozens of separate pools, this still doesn't tell me what error is causing all of this.

What's the best approach to narrow down the application and error causing this?

Comment: A very long list of possible causes are out there if you search the error message "is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool", so don't expect a concrete answer can be provided. If you cannot resolve it via common options such as switching application pool identity, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com so that Microsoft support engineer can assist you.

Comment: IIS comes with a feature called Rapid-Fail Protection. By default an App Pool is configured to become disabled if a worker in the pool crashes 5 times within a 5 minute span. the thresholds of this setting are able to be modified by right clicking on the App Pool going to Advanced Settings and modifying the 'Rapid-Fail Protection' properties. However, this event indicates that there is likely a serious issue in your application that needs to be resolved.